# Sort meta-value in the sequence array in pre_get_post

Tags: php, pre-get-posts, meta-value

I am customizing the display of posts in a category with pre_get_posts and meta_value . Each will receive a meta_value posts and wish them to be in the order of the array.

I want it that way ( 1 ) sec_a ( 2 ) sec_c ( 3 ) sec_b. It turns out that the order is the initials of the letters and the result looks like sec_a, sec_b and sec_c. How can I fix?

```
function pregp_wpse_97354($qry) {
  if (is_category(2) && is_main_query()) {
    $qry->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'post-2' ));
    $qry->set('cat',2);
    $qry->set('posts_per_page',10);
    $itens = array(1 => 'sec_a', 3 => 'sec_b', 2 => 'sec_c' );
    $meta_query = array(
          array(
            'key'     => 'sec_special',
            'value'   => $itens,
            'compare' => 'IN',
    )); 
    $qry->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $qry->set('orderby', 'meta-value');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_97354');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your order seems arbitrary, so there is no clear way to express it as query parameters. The closest to micromanaging order is by `post__in`, but then you have to have *all* post IDs and it won't be sane at all for any significant amount of posts.

You might want to simply create and fill another custom field with value that *is* alphabetically sortable.